# Cannot use rand

Tags: c

current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(0);

    printf("%i", rand());
}
```

when I try to compile with gcc or clang as

> clang index.c

> gcc index.c

I get

> index.c:12:5: error: call to undeclared function 'srand'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> srand(0);
> ^

> index.c:16:18: error: call to undeclared function 'rand'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> printf("%i", rand());

Any idea what I'm missing? The code compiles when using VSCode's run command

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand

Comment: When using the C standard library functions, you need to #include the proper headers for the functions you use. VSCode probably includes "windows.h", which in turn include 100s of header files.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```